# Assigning object pointers

Tags: objective-c, pointers, variable-assignment

Is this pointer assignment correct?

```
customclass.somearray = &*otherarray;
```

where `somearray` and `otherarray` are `NSArray` objects.
If not, how do I solve my problem:
I want to share this `otherarray` object with `customclass.somearray`. And I want all changes
made to `customclass.somearray` to be made to the original `otherarray` too.
Doing it this way, it works. I just want to ask, is it correct?

Comment: if the property is assign type, yes. Be careful with memory management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two variables are pointers of the same type, so just assign one to the other:

```
customclass.somearray = otherarray;
```

The way you have written this is unnecessary. Using the dereference operator `*` essentially gives you the "contents" of the pointer. The address-of operator `&` correspondingly gives you the address of whatever you apply it to. Your pointer `otherarray` contains an address. If you dereference that address and then take the address of that, you end up right back where you started.

Be aware that the left side of this assignment is a property access (assuming that `customclass` is also an object and not just a `struct`). This means that the compiler will change your expression into:

```
[customclass setSomearray:&*otherarray];
// And my version will be changed into:
[customclass setSomearray:otherarray];
```

That is, it becomes a method call rather than a simple assignment. This does not affect the syntax you should use, however.

Comment: so if i'll change my somearray in custom class the changes will be in otherarray too?

Comment: Yes, although that can be an error-prone thing to do. You should consider putting your array in a separate model class and have your other objects access it through that class only when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

When working in Objective-C, you never deal with objects directly, but always refer to them via pointers. Always. In C++, you can declare an actual object on the stack, for example, but you never do that in Objective-C. So, if you have:

```
NSArray *otherArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil];
```

then otherArray is a pointer to an instance of NSArray. Likewise, your `somearray` property will be of type `NSArray*`, so the types will match and you can just assign one to the other:

```
customclass.somearray = otherarray;
```

Hope that helps.